# reliable approach to unescape HTML Characters in java (Android)

Tags: java, android, html, escaping, html-encode

I didn't find any approach except replacing myself to unescape any kind of HTML Charaters in a reliable way.

StringEscapeUtils currently seems the best for my, but it doesn't work for any case:

My Code:

```
@Test
public void escapeHTMLChars2() {
    String sample1 = "&lt;";
    Assert.assertEquals("<", org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(sample1));
    String sample2 = "&ndash;";
    Assert.assertEquals("–", org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(sample2));
}
```

gradle:

```
implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.11'
```

leads to:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :-
Actual   :?
```

Is there a way to unescape all kinds of HTML chars without hacking ?

Comment: What is `StringEscapeUtils`? Which library is that from? Presumably it's from Apache Commons, but which library (Lang or Text) and which version?

Comment: **Unable to reproduce.** Tested with `commons-lang3 3.11` and with `commons-text 1.9`. --- Please note that the `–` in the second `assertEquals()` call in the code is a ['EN DASH' (U+2013)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm), but the `-` in the `Expected` line of the output is a ['HYPHEN-MINUS' (U+002D)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/002d/index.htm), so *that* output wasn't generated from *that* code.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I gave more info. Lib is  commons-lang3.